# Events not Working

Tags: c#, .net, events

My custom Class events not working. 
Here is my code:

```
public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, int p);
```

When I am not using `delegate { }`, I am getting error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an Object.

```
public event EventHandler DownloadCompleted = delegate { };
public event ChangedEventHandler DownloadProgressChanged = delegate { };

public void DownloadFile(String url, String localFilename)
{

    try
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        byte[] downloadedData = new byte[0];

        int downloaded = 0;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int totalData = (int)response.ContentLength;
        int a = 0;

        FileStream file = File.Create(localFilename);

        while (true)
        {

            if (paused == false)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    file.Flush();
                    file.Close();
                    DownloadCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
                    break;
                }
                file.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                downloaded += bytesRead;
                DownloadProgressChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty, downloaded);
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }

}
```

using in other class like this:

```
Downloader dw = new Downloader();
dw.DownloadFile(txt_url.Text, txt_path.Text);
dw.DownloadCompleted += dw_DownloadCompleted;
dw.Changed +=dw_Changed;

void wb_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
}

void wb_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender,DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Setting ProgressBar Value
    progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

But ProgressBar not working.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign event handlers in your "other" class **before** calling 
`DownloadFile`:

```
Downloader dw = new Downloader();
dw.DownloadCompleted += dw_DownloadCompleted;
dw.Changed +=dw_Changed;
dw.DownloadFile(txt_url.Text, txt_path.Text);
```

You also don't need to assign empty event handlers like `= delegate { }`.

Otherwise at the time when `DownloadFile` tries to call `DownloadCompleted` and `Changed` event handlers - they are null references, that's why you're getting that error. Assigning empty event handlers prevents `NullReferenceException`, but since you're assigning empty event handlers to your events - they obviously do nothing.

Comment: The OP needs to check whether `DownloadProgressChanged` is null before calling it. There's no guarantee that there will be any subscribers.  In C# 6 the problem can be fixed by changing `DownloadProgressChanged(...)` to `DownloadProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, ...)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the essential error was not lack of checking of event handler to be null before calling it (though these checks are really missing in the OP's code), but incorrect order of assigning event handlers and method calling caused this handlers to be nulls.

Comment: There is no correct order of assigning event handlers. There may be no event handlers to assign - what if one didn't want to track progress?  One *has* to check for null before calling the delegate.

Comment: +1 for Panagiotis Kanavos, you should check for null before raising events  instead of relying that there will always be a listener.

Comment: I'm not declaring "there is no need to check event handlers for null before calling" - because it should be such a checks with no doubts.  I'm not talking about "order of assigning" of event handlers, just pointing OP's attention to the fact this assignment has to be done before calling the method that uses these handlers. Otherwise next question from OP would be "I'm not getting any exception, but why my event handlers was not called?"